# Absolute links within own domain in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I would like to create an absolute link to files (images, downloads, ...) in my `static` directory, so during development the link would be `http://localhost/myimage.jpg` and once deployed it should be `https://www.example.com/myimage.jpg`.

Is there an easy way (e.g. an environment variable etc.) to reference the current domain name in Gatsby?

I would like to achieve this behavior without changing any config files.

A relative link is not an option in my case. The reason is that I am using the plugin `gatsby-plugin-react-intl` which modifies all relative links by adding the locale in front of it, meaning, the above mentioned link would automatically turn into `https://www.example.com/en/myimage.jpg` instead of `https://www.example.com/myimage.jpg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is what you described. Using the [static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/), a structure like `/static/myimage.jpg` will be referenced as `https://somedomain.com/myimage.jpg`.

The same approach applies to PDF or any static asset you wish to make available.

Following that, a structure like: /static/images/myimage.jpg will become `https://somedomain.com/images/myimage.jpg`.

Keep in mind that the static folder structure is "cloned" inside the public one once the site is built so everything inside will become public. `/static` becomes the root path once cloned.

> I know that this is the default behavior. The problem is, that I'm
> using `react-intl` (or more specifically, `gatsby-plugin-react-intl`),
> which modifies all these paths by adding the locale in front of it,
> e.g. `<img src='/myimage.jpg' /`> becomes `<img src='/en/myimage.jpg />`.
> Using gatsby-image for all purposes is not possible, because it
> doesn't work with SVGs etc. I haven't figured out how to stop the
> plugin from doing this and I thought knowing how to refer to a your
> own domain in js (or react) would be something worth knowing.

Well, there are multiple ways to point to your current domain. From the `window.location.origin` ([check caveats of using `window` or global objects in SSR](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/)) to the default [`location` `props` exposed by Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/) (because its extension from `@reach/router`, from React). Note that `location` `props` will be only available in top-level components (pages) but you can drill down or use it as you wish, as any other property.

In addition, the `gatsby-plugin-react-intl` plugin exposes some methods that provide the current language information, useful to build your own static path to the asset. Using:

```
  const { locale } = useIntl();
```

Will give you the current locale. You can use it to build your own asset like:

```
  <img src={`/${locale}/images/myimage.jpg`} />
```

This path will work whether you are in local development or in your hosted project domain, because of the relativity. If you still want to use the full domain, you can use the previously explained `location` (React-based approach) or the `window.location` (JavaScript-based approach).

Regarding the automatic modification of static assets and paths, I'm afraid it's the default plugin's behavior and I haven't found any way or exposed method to change it otherwise.

Comment: I know that this is the default behavior. The problem is, that I'm using react-intl (or more specifically, gatsby-plugin-react-intl), which modifies all these paths by adding the locale in front of it, e.g. `<img src='/myimage.jpg' />` becomes `<img src='/en/myimage.jpg />`. Using gatsby-image for all purposes is not possible, because it doesn't work with SVGs etc.
I haven't figured out how to stop the plugin from doing this and I thought knowing how to refer to a your own domain in js (or react) would be something worth knowing.

Comment: That would be a detail to know beforehand xD. I've added a few workarounds, maybe they will do the trick for your use-case

Comment: I wanted to phrase the question as short as possible, but I see your point. I edited my original post now to explain it.
Thanks for your detailed answer! I will try out your workaround.
By the way, the way you described to build your own asset link `<img src={\`/${locale}/images/myimage.jpg\`} />` would then lead to `/en/en/images/myimage.jpg`, as the plugin would add another `/en` to the link as described in the initial problem - been there, done that :)

Comment: It shouldn't as long as the path is relative (starting with slash) and you are just pointing a source (locale=en, not `/en/en`). The path should be valid :/

Comment: You are right! I missed the detail with the slash, my bad

Comment: I just tried to replicate what you wrote and by doing so I realized that I somehow forgot to add the slash from the very beginning! I was looking at the problem for such a long time already that I didn't see the obvious anymore. Oh my god, what a stupid mistake. Thanks so much for pointing that out to me! Now my inital problem is solved as well